# Xamarin.iOS app crashes with a message SIGABRT 0x1008bc000 + 53902324

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crash, monodevelop

We are experiencing the following crash (logged in appcenter) from one of our iOS apps that was developed using Xamarin.iOS. The user device is an iPhone SE (2nd generation) running iOS 16.2, and we are unable to reproduce this issue in a local environment.

We have no idea where to start looking into for resolving this crash, and the community is also providing little to no information.

If someone knows what this crash means, it will be easier to identify the root cause.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first thing would be to symbolicate the crash report, otherwise everyone would just be guessing